# Plotting many samples over time with error bars with matlibplot-whatever I try receives errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, plot

I am new to matlibplot and I have been trying off and on to figure out how to plot with matlibplot instead of prism to make my work faster, but it is actually making it much slower as everything I try gives an error.
I have this dataframe "final" with 163 timepoints and 18 samples (in triplicate). I wanted to plot the mean over time with standard deviation error bars and a different colored line for each sample. I didn't think it would be so impossibly difficult.

The attempt that I think is the closest looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#code to analyze data and create final dataframe (called "final"):
  #some code here

#find the mean and std of each sample which are in triplicate from the final dataframe:

mean=final.groupby(np.arange(len(final.columns))//3, axis=1).mean()
std=final.groupby(np.arange(len(final.columns))//3, axis=1).std()

#insert is a dataframe with 163 timepoints, the x value (i.e. time=0, time=0.34 etc)
plt.errorbar(insert,mean,yerr=std, label="work please")
plt.show
```

I get the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)"
even though I checked all data frames are 163 timepoints long and mean and std have 18 samples so they should be the same dimensions. I tried converting the dataframes to numpy array because some said that was required but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated as I've scoured the internet for far too long. Also how can I keep the names each sample which is in the data frame when plotting?

Update: I got it to sort of work using the Pandas plot instead of matlibplot. I can see all my samples and data bars but not modify the x or y axis.
I did:

```
  mean.plot(yerr=std)
```

However when I try to add in the x values (as below) the error bars disappear:

```
mean.insert(0,"Elapsed", insert, True)
mean.set_index("Elapsed", inplace=True)
mean.plot(  yerr=std)
```

How to fix this?

Image of final data frame for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#code to analyze data and create final dataframe (called "final"):
#some code here

#find the mean and std of each sample which are in triplicate from the final dataframe:
mean = final.groupby(np.arange(len(final.columns))//3, axis=1).mean()
std = final.groupby(np.arange(len(final.columns))//3, axis=1).std()

#plot mean with error bars and different colored lines for each sample
insert = range(1, 164)
for i in range(mean.shape[1]):
    plt.errorbar(insert, mean.iloc[:, i], yerr=std.iloc[:, i], label=mean.columns[i])
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Elapsed')
plt.ylabel('Mean')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've actually tried that as well already. It gives the same result as doing mean.setIndex. I can see the x axis but the error bars disapear.

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample dataset?

Comment: I shared a sample image above of the "final" data frame. The index goes down to 163 with more columns as well but that shouldn't matter. It seems I cannot post files here and it is too big to copy and paste. I could share via google drive if need be. I think final data frame is not very unique so it's usage shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think the problem might have to do with your insert. Can you try the modified code and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks! I tried it I am getting error bars and a graph. The legend is just numbers but I think we can add it like this.    col=0
i=0
names= [None] * (int)(len(final.columns)/3)
while col<len(final.columns):
  names[i]=final.columns[col]
  col+=3
  i+=1
mean.columns=names
std.columns=names

Comment: Why does the original plt not work well. Why do we need: for i in range(mean.shape[1]):
    plt.errorbar(insert, mean.iloc[:, i], yerr=std.iloc[:, i], label=mean.columns[i])?   mean.shape    My understanding is this goes from i to the number of points in mean and plots from 0 to i each time through the loop?

Comment: It is needed because technically you have multiple sets of data, one for the mean and one for std. The for loop iterates over each column for all the dataframes so it can plot multiple sets of data on the same graph.